# An hyperboloid of one sheet which intersects a torus along a circle centered at the origin in the $z=0$ plane

Tags: differential-geometry, solution-verification

I'm mostly interested in getting some confirmation that the reasoning employed in method 2 is fine and without error.

Hyperboloid (one sheet):

$$\frac{x^{2}+y^2}{\left(R-r\right)^{2}}-\frac{z^{2}}{p^{2}\left(R-r\right)^{2}}=1$$

Torus:

$$(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-R)^2+z^2=r^2$$

What must the value of $p$ be in order for the two surfaces to have the same mean curvature at every point along their circular intersection?

This is the progress I've made:

#### Method 1

First, give each of the surfaces a parametrization

Hyperboloid: $H(\theta,\psi)=(x,y,z)$
$$x=\left(R-r\right)\cosh\left(\psi\right)\cos \theta\ $$
$$y=\left(R-r\right)\cosh\left(\psi\right)\sin \theta$$
$$z=\left(R-r\right)p\sinh \psi$$

Torus: $T(\theta,\psi)=(x,y,z)$
$$x=\left(R+r\cos \psi\right)\cos\theta$$
$$y=\left(R+r\cos \psi\right)\sin\theta$$
$$z=r\sin \psi$$

From the parametrization of the hyperboloid we can derive the shape operator:

$$\pmatrix{\frac{-p}{(R-r)\sqrt{\sinh^{2}\psi+p^{2}\cosh^{2}\psi}}&0\\\ 0&\frac{p}{(R-r)(\sinh^{2}\psi+p^{2}\cosh^{2}\psi)^{3/2}}}$$

The circular intersection of the hyperboloid and the torus corresponds to $\psi=0$ on the hyperboloid, so to obtain the mean curvature at an arbitrary point on that circle we can simply evaluate the above shape operator at $\psi=0$, giving us

$$\pmatrix{\frac{1}{r-R}&0\\\ 0&\frac{1}{(R-r)p^2}}$$

Half the trace of this matrix is $$\frac{1-p^2}{2p^{2}(R-r)}$$ $\tag1$

The mean curvature of the torus at any point along the circle of intersection is $$\frac{1}{2r}+\frac{1}{2(r-R)}$$ $\tag2$

Setting (1) and (2) equal to one another allows us to solve for $p$ and we see that

$$p=±\sqrt{\frac{r}{R-r}}$$

#### Method 2

We can reduce the dimension of this problem by observing that all along the circle of intersection one of the principal curvatures of the hyperboloid must necessarily be the same as one of the principal curvatures of the torus.

What we then have is an easier problem where we need only find the curvature of an hyperbola and then find the $p$ value necessary to make the circle be an osculating circle of the hyperbola.

The circle is given by

$$\left(x-R\right)^{2}+y^{2}=r^{2}$$

and the curvature of this circle at $(R-r,0)$ is $$\frac{1}{r}$$

The hyperboloid is given by

$$\frac{x^{2}}{\left(R-r\right)^{2}}-\frac{y^{2}}{p^{2}\left(R-r\right)^{2}}=1$$

and the curvature of this hyperbola at $(R-r,0)$ is $$\frac{1}{(R-r)p^2}$$

Setting these curvatures equal to one another gives us

$$p=\sqrt{\frac{r}{R-r}}$$

Then, we can just observe that the sign of $p$ does not affect the hyperbola generated by
$$\frac{x^{2}+y^2}{\left(R-r\right)^{2}}-\frac{z^{2}}{p^{2}\left(R-r\right)^{2}}=1$$

Therefore

$$p=±\sqrt{\frac{r}{R-r}}$$