# An elliptic hyperboloid of one sheet which intersects an asymmetric torus along an ellipse centered at the origin in the $z=0$ plane

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

This is a generalization of the problem [An hyperboloid of one sheet which intersects a torus along a circle centered at the origin in the $z=0$ plane](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4805697/an-hyperboloid-of-one-sheet-which-intersects-a-torus-along-a-circle-centered-at)

Elliptic hyperboloid: $H(\theta,\psi)=(x,y,z)$, $\theta$ $\in$ $[0,2\pi)$, $\psi$ $\in$ $ℝ$

$$x=\left(a-r\right)\cosh\left(\psi\right)\cos \theta $$
$$y=\left(b-r\right)\cosh\left(\psi\right)\sin \theta$$
$$z=p\sinh \psi$$

Torus: $T(\theta,\psi)=(x,y,z)$, $\theta$ $\in$ $[0,2\pi)$, $\psi$ $\in$ $[0,2\pi)$

$$x=(a+r\cos\left(\psi\right))\cos \theta $$
$$y=(b+r\cos\left(\psi\right))\sin \theta $$
$$z=r\sin \psi$$

What must the value of $p$ be in order for the two surfaces to intersect only along an ellipse in the $z=0$ plane?

---

Let $c=\max(a,b)$

Slice the hyperboloid and the torus simultaneously with the planes $x=0$ and $y=0$ and consider the cross-sections, each of which is a hyperbola or a pair of circles.

We then choose a hyperbola from the two hyperbolas depending on whether $a>b$ or $a<b$.

The chosen hyperbola has a parametrization of the form

$$\left(\left(c-r\right)\cosh t,p\sinh t\right)$$

From this parametrization we can derive that the curvature of the hyperbola at $t=0$ is $\frac{c-r}{p^2}$

Setting this equal to the curvature at $t=\pi$ of either of the circles which make up the cross section of the torus (which is just $1/r$) we can then solve for $p$ and we see that

$$p=±\sqrt{r(c-r)}$$

[Here in desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/zt4oca0qxp) you can roughly see that if $|p|<\sqrt{r(c-r)}$ then the two surfaces will intersect along multiple curves.

Thus, my answer to the question is that $|p|≥\sqrt{r(c-r)}$

Comment: @JeanMarie the parametrization I provide for said torus should clarify exactly what type of surface I'm trying to specify

Comment: @JeanMarie according to my graph in desmos it's asymmetric, since I set $a=5.7$ and $b=10$ https://www.desmos.com/calculator/zt4oca0qxp

Comment: This is not right. Don't you mean to have parentheses in your parametrization of the torus? I bet you are not typing what you have into desmos.

Comment: @TedShifrin I fixed a typo; try now?

Comment: So it would look more like a torus if you put parentheses: $x=(a+r\cos\psi)\cos\theta$, $y=(b+r\cos\psi)\sin\theta$. You're rotating a vertical circle about an *ellipse* instead of a *circle*. I don't know that it's totally asymmetric, but it's not the usual torus.

Comment: @TedShifrin can we grant that this sort of non-usual torus technically qualifies as asymmetric in some weak sense? The weak sense is all I mean to invoke. I've put a new set of parentheses on; is the issue fixed? I shouldn't call it an elliptic torus, because that term refers to something different

Comment: @TedShifrin I don't see why $x=a\cos (\theta)+r\cos\left(\psi\right)\cos \theta$ isn't exactly the same thing as $x=(a+r\cos\left(\psi\right))\cos (\theta)$

Comment: Of course it is, but the reason the standard parametrization is written with parentheses is that then the geometry is more transparent. If you look in multivariable calculus and differential geometry texts, you’ll find it my way all (or almost all) of the time. Yes, an elliptic torus is made by rotating an ellipse around a circle; you have done the reverse.

Comment: @TedShifrin I had no idea. That's a neat little fun fact about what's standard in math texts.